# rm command: remove files with file names containing brackets

Tags: windows-7, command-line, bash, rm, mingw

I am trying to remove all files in a Windows 7 directory with filenames containing brackets; `(` and `)`:

Using MinGW:

`rm *(*)*`

I get an error:

`sh: syntax error near unexpected token '('`

I assume this is because the `rm` command sees a bracket as some sort of special input. What could I do instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "escape" specific metacharacters by prefixing with backslash.

```
$ touch 'aaa(bbb)ccc'
$ rm *\(*\)*
$ ls
$
```

Comment: `rm '*(*)*'` gives me `rm: cannot lstat `*(*)*': No such file or directory`. `rm *\(*\)*` works (but also wants to delete directories with this match but that's what the original of the OP wants too, giving an error-line).

Comment: Using quotes did not work for me. The escape backslash did though. @Rik - Apologies - I was not specific. The directory I am looking at has no sub-directories.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick The first method **only** works on the **one** file named `*(*)*`, but OP wants to work on **all** files **containing** `(` and `)`. Try it yourself with a `touch 'a(b)c'`. Then `rm '*(*)*'` does not work on **all** these files. Also not in bash on Linux! The `rm *\(*\)*` does work on both Linux and mingw.

Comment: @Rik: Thanks, I was aware of that (which is why I mentioned "all metacharacters") - but maybe it is confusing to include that in this answer - I'll remove it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following:

```
find . -type f -name "*(*)*" -delete -maxdepth 1
```

For testing I would use the `-print` argument first:

```
find . -type f -name "*(*)*" -print -maxdepth 1
```

If you want to do it in all subdirectories you can ommit the `-maxdepth 1`

If the `-delete` does not work you can try:

```
find . -type f -name "*(*)*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

*Edit:* Included the `-type f` to only do this on files (and not directories) same as in `rm`.